# How do I turn off electric "double-dollar" insert under auctex?

Tags: latex, auctex

Inserting a `$` symbol in a latex document (in AucTex mode) automatically inserts 2 `$`s in a row (and then hitting "delete" immediately deletes both). I can confirm that the variable `TeX-electric-math` is `nil`. What other variables can be causing this behavior? I'd like to disable it.

Comment: Here, hitting backspace delete both, but hitting delete only delete the second one.

Comment: Always test with `emacs -Q` and maybe `M-x package-initialize` if you use `package.el`. Always give version information in the question: 1.: `M-x emacs-version`, 2.: `M-x locate-library latex`. If the problem disappears with `emacs -Q` find the problem by bisecting your init file(s).